# No overload matches delegate

Tags: c#, delegates, method-invocation

Thanks to a question previously answered on this website, I've built a little block of code. Unfortunately, I've been getting an error that I don't quite understand. Here's the block of code:

```
        private void AddTextToUpListBox(string text)
    {
        if (lbxServersThatAreUp.InvokeRequired)
        {
            lbxServersThatAreUp.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(AddTextToUpListBox), new object[] { });
            return;
        }

        lbxServersThatAreUp.Items.Add(text);
    }
```

The error I'm getting is "No Overload for 'AddTextToUpListBox' matches delegate 'System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker'"

So I tried changing the following line like so:

```
lbxServersThatAreUp.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(AddTextToUpListBox(text)), new object[] { });
```

but if I do that, it just says "Method name expected". What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MethodInvoker` is a delegate with no parameters - you've *got* a parameter. Two options:

- Use an `Action<string>`:

  ```
  lbxServersThatAreUp.Invoke((Action<string>)AddTextToUpListBox,
                             new object[] { text });
  ```
- Use a lambda expression to create a `MethodInvoker`:

  ```
  MethodInvoker invoker = () => AddTextToUpListBox(text);
  lbxServersThatAreUp.Invoke(invoker);
  ```

Comment: @msarchet: No, because the `Invoke` method parameter is just `Delegate`, and the C# compiler doesn't know what type of method you're trying to create.

Comment: Yea, I realized that as soon as I asked it.

Comment: Awesome, worked perfectly! Thanks a ton. Plus, I appreciate the explanation. I was a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void AddTextToUpListBox(string text)
{
    if (lbxServersThatAreUp.InvokeRequired)
    {
        lbxServersThatAreUp.Invoke((Action<String>)AddTextToUpListBox, new object[] { text});
        return;
    }

    lbxServersThatAreUp.Items.Add(text);
}
```

You need to pass in the parameters for the method, you should also be able to pass the method directly as the delegate.

Comment: I don't think that will compile, because you haven't specified which delegate type it's trying to convert AddTextToUpListBox to.

Comment: @JonSkeet correct. I thought I had dropped an Action<String> in there.